# Popup SendMessage to Background Service Worker (MV3) Cannot Establish Connection

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

### Update

It seems like webpack is causing the issues.

If I replace the `dist/background.js` with:

```js
console.log("background is running"); // Now visible ✅

const handler = (req, sender, sendResponse) => {
  switch (req.type) {
    case "message":
      sendResponse({ data: "hi" });
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handler);
```

Both the console log (in service worker) and response (in popup) are observed. Also, there are no errors.

Time to investigate further

### Update #2

Upon further inspection, I noticed that the webpack output is wrapped in a function, but never called:

```js
{
    /***/ "./src/background.ts":
      /*!***************************!*\
  !*** ./src/background.ts ***!
  \***************************/
      /***/ (function () {
        console.log("background is running");
        const handler = (req, sender, sendResponse) => {
          switch (req.type) {
            case "message":
              sendResponse({ data: "hi" });
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        };
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handler);

        /***/
      }) // <==== adding () will make it an IIFE and everything works!
  },
```

Question is how to automate this?

### Update #3

Seems like the IIFE trick I mentioned above only works when there are no imports in `background.js`. As soon as I add any import, I get an error that the background script is not valid.

Adding module type property to background **does not** help:

```json
// manifest.json
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  ...
}
```

### Update #4

Turns out this was caused by vendor splitting optimization in webpack:

```json
// webpack.config.json
{
  ...
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          enforce: true,
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  ...
}
```

Once I removed this, everything started working properly!
Would be nice to keep this around, but it is just an optimization after all, so if it breaks things, best to get rid of it.

How I figured this out? Well as I mentioned, everything worked a couple of commits ago. Back then I didn't have this optimization, so I tried removing it again, and everything started working again like magic.

### Original Question

I had this working previously, so I am sure my setup is correct, but regardless of what I try, I now get

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Also, I cannot find a solution online which indicates anything that differs from my setup.

#### Here is a MWE

dist folder structure:

```
dist/background.js
dist/index.html
dist/manifest.json
dist/popup.js
dist/runtime.js
dist/vendors.js
other misc files
```

```json
// manifest.json
{
  ...
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

```js
// src/components/App.tsx
export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'someMessage' }, ({ data }) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }, []);
 
  ...
}
```

```js
// src/background.ts
import { TSentResponse } from "./typings/background";
import { executeResponse } from "./utils/background";

console.log('sanity check'); // <=== does not fire 


// also doesn't seem to be called 
const handleMessage = (req: { type: string }, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender, res: (response?: unknown) => void) => {
  switch (req.type) {
    case 'someMessage':
      // an IIFE (worked fine before)
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

  return true; // due to asynchronous nature
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```

My service worker is registered properly:

[image: Service Worker In Extensions Page]

When I said above that I cannot see the logs for background, I mean when I check in the service worker dev tools (from above image), not the popup dev tool.

When I open the popup, I get the following errors:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

I also don't see the service worker actually being registered - it did register before...

[image: Service Worker Registering]

Is this a bug with MV3?

My [repository](https://github.com/lbragile/tabmerger/tree/develop) (not fully up to date, but can be used to quickly check the above)

Comment: Don't register the service worker, it happens automatically when you install the extension.

Comment: I don’t manually register it, I mainly tried to debug to see that it was being registered as I ran out of ideas for why there is no receiving end when I sendMessage to the background script. Any ideas?

Comment: Might be https://crbug.com/1271154.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be what I am seeing. Used to work, but now does not even register. Hopefully this can be resolved soon 

Comment: The following seems to also be related: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/POU6sW-I39M

Comment: So it seems like my webpack config is causing this, see the update in my post. Not sure how to fix, would be very appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Figured out that this was caused by vendor splitting in webpack (see update #4 in question above).

Comment: You just saved me hours of debugging, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. To send a message from the popup.js to the background service worker, first you need to get  **current tab id**. to get the current tab id do as below:

   **popup.js**

   ```
   const messageKey = 'key-message-from-popup-to-background';

   // Listen to get current tab info from the content_popup 
   document.addEventListener('_listener_getCurrentTabInfo', function (e) {
       const tab = e.detail.response;

       // Send a message to the background,js
       chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, messageKey);
   });

   // Send message to content_popup to get current tab info
   document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('_dispatch_getCurrentTabInfo'));
   ```

   **content_popup.js**

   ```
   const config = {
       scripts: [
           // add ".js" files to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
           "popup/popup.js"
       ]
   };

   // Listen to get current tab info from the background.js
   document.addEventListener('_dispatch_getCurrentTabInfo', function (e) {

       // Key to help 
       const type = 'get_current_tab_info';

       // Send a message to the background.js to get current tab info
       chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: type}, response => {
           document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('_listener_getCurrentTabInfo', {detail: {'response': response}}));
       });
   });

   // prepare and add scripts
   var scriptList = config['scripts'];

   for (var i = 0; i < scriptList.length; i++) {
       var s = document.createElement('script');
       s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(scriptList[i]);
       s.onload = function () {
           this.remove();
       };
       (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
   }
   ```

   **background.js**

   ```
   // Get messages
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

       // If request related to fetch data from API
       if (request.url && request.url !== '') {

           // Fetch http request and send back the response
           fetch(request.url, request.init).then(function (response) {

               return response.text().then(function (text) {
                   sendResponse([{
                       body: text,
                       status: response.status,
                       statusText: response.statusText,
                   }, null]);
               });
           }, function (error) {
               sendResponse([null, error]);
           });

           // If request do not related to fetch data from API
       } else {
           detectMessageType(request, sender, sendResponse);
       }

       return true;
   });

   function detectMessageType(request, sender, sendResponse) {

       // Check background request type
       if (request && request.type) {
           switch (request.type) {
               case 'get_current_tab_info': {
                   getCurrentTabInfo(tab => {

                       // Send current tab info back to content_popup
                       sendResponse(tab);
                   });

                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   });

   function getCurrentTabInfo(callback) {
       chrome.tabs.query({
           active: true,
           currentWindow: true
       }, function (tab) {
           callback(tab[0]);
       });
   }
   ```
2. Get message in **contentScript**

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, response) => {
       const message = message;
       // Write your codes
   });
   ```
3. This is the project structure (partial)

   ```
   Project
     -- popup
     ---- popup.js
     ---- content_popup.js
     ---- popup.html
     ---- popup.css
     -- content_extension.js
     -- background.js
     -- manifest.js
   ```
4. Add the following code to the end of the body tag inside the popup.html file

   ```
   <script src="content_popup.js"></script>
   ```
5. Update the manifest.json file like below

   ```
   "manifest_version": 3,
   .
   .
   .
   "content_scripts": [
       {
           "js": [
               "content_extension.js"
           ]
       }
   ],
   "action": {
       "default_icon": ...,
       "default_title": ...,
       "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
   },
   "background": {
       "service_worker": "background.js"
   },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
       {
           "resources": [
               "popup/popup.html",
               "popup/popup.js"
           ]
       }
   ],
   ...
   ```